# How to disabled textfield when i click the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to disable the div when i click the the checkbox. if the current address and permanent address are the same, the user just click the check box to disabled the field of the permanent address. Thanks!

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">Current and Permanent Address are the same.
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div rv-each-address="applicant:personal_information:addresses">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label"><strong  rv-text="address:description">Permanent Address</strong></label>
                 <input class="form-control" rv-value="address:address"
                    name="model.cid" data-validate="required" />
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label> <input
                    rv-value="address:city" rv-enabled="address:province" type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="city"
                    id="city" data-validate="required"
                    placeholder="Current city" />
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="state">Province</label> <input
                    rv-value="address:province" rv-enabled="address:country" type="text" id="province" placeholder="Select Province"
                    name="province" class="form-control typeahead">
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="country">Country</label> 
                 <select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender">
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
                 <option>Philippines</option>
                 <option>Hong Kong</option>
                 <option>South Korea</option>
                 <option>Singapore</option>
                 <option>China</option>
              </select> 
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="postalCode">Postal
                 Code</label> <input class="form-control" rv-value="address:postalCode" name="postalCode"
                    id="postalCode" data-validate="required"
                    placeholder="Zip Code" />
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: What checkbox? I can't seem to find any checkboxes in your code...

Comment: Updated Sir. Sorry...

Comment: the permanent address field, city, province and country

Comment: Will this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/88dz3fm7/

Comment: It works dude. but i change my script into this

Comment: <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#checkbox').change(function(){
       var div = $('#everything');
        if (div.attr('class')!="disabled") {
         div.addClass("disabled");
         $("#everything *").attr("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
          div.removeClass("disabled");
          $('#everything *').attr('disabled',false);
        }
      });
     });
     </script>

Comment: Can you post that as a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lazoskenneth/88dz3fm7/2/

Comment: Check that. It's working :) Thanks @k97513

Comment: If possible, could you accept my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following JS to your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $('.permanentAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">Current and Permanent Address are the same.
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div rv-each-address="applicant:personal_information:addresses">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-group ">
                 <label class="control-label"><strong  rv-text="address:description">Permanent Address</strong></label>
                 <input class="form-control permanentAdd" rv-value="address:address"
                    name="model.cid" data-validate="required" />
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label> <input
                    rv-value="address:city" rv-enabled="address:province" type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="city"
                    id="city" data-validate="required"
                    placeholder="Current city" />
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="state">Province</label> <input
                    rv-value="address:province" rv-enabled="address:country" type="text" id="province" placeholder="Select Province"
                    name="province" class="form-control typeahead">
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="country">Country</label> 
                 <select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender">
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
                 <option>Philippines</option>
                 <option>Hong Kong</option>
                 <option>South Korea</option>
                 <option>Singapore</option>
                 <option>China</option>
              </select> 
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label" for="postalCode">Postal
                 Code</label> <input class="form-control" rv-value="address:postalCode" name="postalCode"
                    id="postalCode" data-validate="required"
                    placeholder="Zip Code" />
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_box" onchange="set_status();">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="control-label" for="postalCode">Postal
                             Code</label> <div id="txt_field" name="txt_field"> </div>   

                <script type="text/javascript">


function set_status() {
        var appendData = '';
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("check_box");
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            appendData = '<input class="form-control" rv-value="address:postalCode" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" readonly="readonly" data-validate="required"   placeholder="Zip Code" />';
        }
        else {
            appendData = '<input class="form-control" rv-value="address:postalCode" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" data-validate="required"   placeholder="Zip Code" />';
        }
        window.jQuery('#txt_field').html(appendData);

    }

            </script>
</div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: have you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how you do this thing easy. make sure you have only one checkbox in this window. else this not working, then you need to change something.

**jQuery**

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function(){
    var n = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if(n){
        $(".permanent-address").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    }else{
        $(".permanent-address").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox">Current and Permanent Address are the same.
    </label>
</div>

<input class="form-control permanent-address" rv-value="address:address" name="model.cid" data-validate="required" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript anwser

```
function checkAddress(checkbox) {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type=checkbox])');
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = checkbox.checked;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].disabled = checkbox.checked;
  }
}
```

HTML code

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAddress(this)">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ba4f7jd/

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a function that gets called when the checkbox is checked, which disables the `div` and all child elements:

```js
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
 var div = $('#everything');
  if (div.attr('class')!="disabled") {
   div.addClass("disabled");
   $("#everything *").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  else {
    div.removeClass("disabled");
    $('#everything *').attr('disabled',false);
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/88dz3fm7/)